# How do I perform a Subversion update on my externals only?

Tags: svn, version-control, externals

We use Subversion for version control, and we share common code among projects using externals. Any given project looks something like this:

- **project/** (*svn:externals is set on this directory*)

  - **externals/** (*this directory is not checked in; it is specified in svn:externals*)

    - **moduleA/** (*this comes from a different repository*)
    - **moduleB/** (*this comes from a different repository*)
  - (*other files and directories here*)

To clarify, the svn:externals property set on the **project/** directory is:

```
http://svnserver/repository/moduleA externals/moduleA
http://svnserver/repository/moduleB externals/moduleB
```

I would like to perform `svn update` on the **project/** directory, but only update the contents of **externals/**. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just doing a svn update on the project\externals directory should work; something like:

```
svn update c:\somedir\project\externals
```

Subversion allows you to update individual sub-directories

Comment: If the parent directory of the external isn't completely updated or if the external directory does not exist (has not been downloaded) the above will not work.  The only way I have found to do this in these cases is to run a manual svn checkout command manually as svn would on an update.  It would be extremely helpful to skip all locals in the parent directory and just update the externals but this does not exist.